# Python MatPlotlib barchart- Resize width

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have written a code to plot a horizontal bar chart using python's matplotlib library.

My goal is to resize the width of the bar chart, but the distance from origin must remain the same, which is 5.6. In short words, my intention is to trim the size in terms of width, keeping the length same. I could not figure out the examples given using subplots.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.rcdefaults()
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy import arange
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('C:\\programming\\Python27\\libra_graphs\\File\\histogram.csv',delimiter=',')
diff = 0
time_lst = []
for row in data:
    if not np.isnan(row[7]):
        diff = row[7]-diff
time_lst.append(diff)

print time_lst,len(time_lst)
y_pos = np.arange(len(time_lst))
print y_pos
val = np.array(diff)
print val

plt.barh(y_pos, val,align='center',height = 0.5 ,color='r',alpha=0.5)
plt.yticks(y_pos)

plt.xlabel('Time(seconds)')
plt.title('Job Execution LIBRA')

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean because we do not have your datafile. Could you upload an image and annotate it to show what you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have plotted 3 bar charts, and the issue is resolved.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.rcdefaults()
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy import arange
import numpy as np

def libra_execution_time():
    data = np.genfromtxt('C:\\programming\\Python27\\libra_graphs\\File\\histogram.csv',delimiter=',')

    hash_diff,key_diff,binary_diff = 0,0,0

    hash_time_lst,key_time_lst,binary_time_lst = [],[],[]

    for row in data:
        if not np.isnan(row[7]):
            hash_diff = row[7]-hash_diff
    hash_time_lst.append(hash_diff)

    for row in data:
        if not np.isnan(row[8]):
            key_diff = row[8]-key_diff
    key_time_lst.append(key_diff)

    for row in data:
        if not np.isnan(row[9]):
            binary_diff = row[9]-binary_diff
    binary_time_lst.append(binary_diff)

    print "#Hash Partitioner--->" ,hash_time_lst,len(hash_time_lst)
    print "#Key Field Partitioenr--->", key_time_lst,len(key_time_lst)
    print "#Binary Partitioner--->",binary_time_lst,len(binary_time_lst)


    #x_lst = (hash_time_lst + key_time_lst + binary_time_lst)
    #print x_lst
    job_time = {"Hash Time":hash_time_lst,"Key_Time":key_time_lst,"Binary Time":binary_time_lst}
    print job_time
    print job_time.keys(),job_time.values()

    y_pos = np.arange(len(job_time.values()))
    print "Y position",y_pos
    val = np.array(job_time.values())
    print val


    plt.barh(y_pos,val ,align='center',height = 0.5 ,color=('r','y','g'))
    plt.yticks(y_pos,job_time.keys())

    plt.xlabel('Time(seconds)')
    plt.ylabel('Performance--->')
    plt.title('Job Execution LIBRA')

    plt.show()

libra_execution_time()
```